# Is ostream& operator<< better practice in a class than using std::cout?

Tags: c++, ostream

In a Linked List class, I created a `display` method to print out the Linked List as it is currently formulated like so:

```cpp
void LinkedList::display() {
   Node* curr = m_head;

   while (curr) {
      std::cout << curr->n_data << " -> ";
      curr = curr->n_next;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

One of the TA's who graded the assignment left a comment:

> Never do cout in a class file. Use `ostream& operator<<` instead.
>
> Classes shouldn't care about where you are outputting to (file/console/etc).

We hadn't yet learned about operator overloading at the time of this assignment, but I'm still not really sure.

How would I actually implement and use the `ostream& operator>>` to print to the console? Why is this best practice?

Comment: It's best prectice exactly for the reason your instructor stated. Actual C++ programs rarely output things directly to console. Although, if you haven't learnt about operator overloading yet, your TA went a bit far with that comment, they should know better.

Comment: The reason to do it: if you implement it as you did, using `cout`, anyone who wants to send the text to standard output can do `display()`, and anyone who wants to send it to e.g. a file, will have no recourse (apart from some redirection black magic). If you use `ostream&`, then the former user can do `display(cout)` and the latter user can construct something like `ofstream fout` and do `display(fout)`. Writing operator overloads is orthogonal to that, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your TA.  There's *NOTHING* wrong with using "cout" as the C++ equivalent of "printf".  Bjarne Stroustrup does it himself ;) Moreover, it's such a common (universal?) idiom that I'd argue your code would be *LESS* readable if you arbitrarily substituted "ostream".  Your TA's argument violates two important principles: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), and [K.I.S.S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: @paul i strongly disagree with you - a display function like this should always allow you to specify where you want the output to go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case would be to add a `std::ostream` parameter to your `display()` method, eg:

```
void LinkedList::display(std::ostream &out) const {
   Node* curr = m_head;

   while (curr) {
      out << curr->n_data << " -> ";
      curr = curr->n_next;
   }
   out << std::endl;
}
```

```
LinkedList list;
...
list.display(std::cout);
```

Then, if down the line, you decide to overload `operator<<`, it can simply call `display()`, eg:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const LinkedList &list) {
    list.display(out);
    return out;
}
```

```
LinkedList list;
...
std::cout << list;
```

Comment: agree, but i think the named function should return the stream

Comment: @NeilButterworth The only reason to ever do that is to support operator chaining, ie: `out << list.display(out) << ...` which is redundant and not very useful when using a named method instead of an operator overload.

Comment: not so - if you did return the stream your << operator could simply return the return value of the display call.  in general, i find any function that returns void suspicious, though harmless in this case. and chaining is useful with named functions. and it is cheap

Comment: @NeilButterworth "*if you did return the stream your `<<` operator could simply return the return value of the `display` call*" - it could, but there is no real benefit to doing so. "*in general, i find any function that returns void suspicious ... and chaining is useful with named functions. and it is cheap*" - that is your opinion. My opinion is it is not worth returning something that would be largely unused by the majority of code. But this is not the place for opinions.

Comment: you will be returning a reference - even if it is not used by most code, it would actually make your << operator one statement shorter, all functions that deal with streams should return the stream, if they can