# Overloading output stream operator: no operator "<<" matches these operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I recently asked the question: [Is ostream& operator<< better practice in a class than using std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74256770/is-ostream-operator-better-practice-in-a-class-than-using-stdcout/74256828#74256828) and got an excellent answer.

When I tried to implement the solution I got errors:

`no operator "<<" matches these operands`

and

`binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'LinkedList' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

The simplest solution in this case would be to add a `std::ostream` parameter to your `display()` method, eg:

## LinkedList.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#pragma once

class LinkedList
{
   struct Node {
      int data = 0;
      Node* prev = nullptr;
      Node* next = nullptr;
   };

private:
   Node* m_head;

public:
   // CONSTRUCTOR
   LinkedList();

   // DESTRUCTOR
   ~LinkedList();

   void display(std::ostream& out) const;
};
```

## LinkedList.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
   m_head = nullptr;
}

void LinkedList::display(std::ostream &out) const {
   Node* curr = m_head;

   while (curr) {
      out << curr->data << " -> ";
      curr = curr->next;
   }
   out << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const LinkedList &list) {
    list.display(out);
    return out;
}
```

## Main.cpp *(generates error)*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main() {

   LinkedList list;
   std::cout << list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some help with this question but it was swiftly deleted...

Essentially the problem is that `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const LinkedList &list)` is not correctly advertised.

We need to add `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const SortedList& list);` to the `LinkedList.h` file within the `LinkedList` class

## LinkedList.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#pragma once

class LinkedList
{
   struct Node {
      int data = 0;
      Node* next = nullptr;
   };

private:
   Node* m_head;

public:
   // CONSTRUCTOR
   LinkedList();

   // DESTRUCTOR
   ~LinkedList();

   void display(std::ostream& out) const;
   
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const LinkedList& list);

};
```

Comment: Note: operator overload usually needs to be declared as `friend`, because it needs to access `private` members of the class, but in your case it only calls a `public` function, so it could also be declared out of class without `friend` keyword.

Comment: That's a good point. I had to declare it as a friend as part of an assignment requirement. But I think you're right that it's not necessary to expose it as friend.

If you post a that as a solution I will support it.